# Notepad++ How to put split HTML tags onto one line using a Find/Replace Regex search?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Suppose I have a document containing this:

```
<div data-test-id="comment">
  <div class="class1 
    class2
    class3">
    <p class="class1">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
</div>
```

The second and third lines have an HTML tag that is split between two lines. I haven't been able to figure out how to bring them onto one line like this:

```
<div data-test-id="comment">
  <div class="class1 class2 class3">
    <p class="class1">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
</div>
```

Whenever I try to use the "?" non-greedy modifier, it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<\w+|\G)(?:(?!>).)*?\K\s+`
- Replace with:   # 1 space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    <           # literally <
    \w+         # 1 or more word character (i.e. tag name)
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)               # end group
(?:             # non capture group (non greedy token)
    (?!>)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't < after
    .           # any character
)*?             # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\s+             # 1 or more any kind of spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: By George, you've done it again, old chap! By this point, it's clear that RegEx is just an alien language that you've somehow mastered.

Comment: @pbarney: Thanks, glad it helps.